# Stange records in access.log apache 2

Tags: http, apache2, http-options-method

Today I notice stange records in access file of my apache 2 webserver

```
::1 - - [25/Jan/2011:14:13:31 +0200] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 -
```

Does anyone know what these lines means ?

Comment: `::1` is the IPv6 address for `localhost`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's an [`OPTIONS` request](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html), which is a feature used by some HTTP clients to query the server:

> The OPTIONS method represents a request for information about the communication options available on the request/response chain identified by the Request-URI. This method allows the client to determine the options and/or requirements associated with a resource, or the capabilities of a server, without implying a resource action or initiating a resource retrieval.

It's commonly used by load balancers, firewalls and proxies to check up on the status of the HTTP server, without actually requesting a resource.

The `::1` at the start is an IPv6 address.